# jQuery Скролл до Элемента содержащего Текст

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, нужен пример скрипта который будет скроллить экран не просто до элемента с якорем, а до элемента который содержит текст "HELLO"

Вот код например

```
<div> WORLD </div>
<div> HELLO </div>
```

Нужно прокрутить до элемента содержащего текст HELLO.

> Повторюсь, как прокручивать до якоря, тоесть задать элементу id и
>   прокручивать до #id я знаю, в данном приложении якорь нельзя
>   использовать, поэтому нужно прокручивать до элемента содержащего текст

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно использовать [contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) в jQuery селекторе

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('div:contains("HELLO")').offset().top
},'slow');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> WORLD </div>
<div> HELLO </div>
```

Comment: Это не ответ, я ведь написал мне нужен скролл без якоря, только до блока содержащего конкретный текст, якорь не получается использовать.

Comment: @S1lllver тогда придется пробегать все элементы и проверять текст, ответ обновил

Comment: ну там функция keyup стоит, проверяет ввод в реальном времени.
вроде то что надо, сейчас проверю

Comment: @S1lllver нашел вариант получше)) обновил

Comment: у меня этот код не работает, не первый не второй, вот весь html


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
<style>
    div {
  height: 1000px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('div:contains("HELLO")').offset().top
},'slow');
</script>


<div> WORLD </div>
<div> HELLO </div>

Comment: Сработало, Автор Ответа добавьте пожалуйста $(document).ready
в начало скрипта, может кто - то непонять, и не будет работать.

Comment: Поправил, спасибо